# What is the difference between "contribute" and "contribute to"

Tags: prepositions

> Indonesia contributed less than 10% of the seafood imports to the US.
> Indonesia contributed **to** less than 10% of the seafood imports to the US.

I do not understand the difference between "contribute (without preposition)" and "contribute to". When should I use the former and when to use the latter? Can anyone explain this to me?

I also read this.
["Contribute for" or "Contribute to" or "Contribute on" or "Contribute in"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177054/contribute-for-or-contribute-to-or-contribute-on-or-contribute-in)

Comment: The first one is fine. The second one is odd to the point of unacceptable. What would you wish the second one to mean? To me it has the sense of, “There is some 10% of US seafood imports of which Indonesia is responsible for some unspecified portion.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  *contribute* something that you give to a collection, when other people are giving things too. For instance, you contribute money to a fund to help the victims of a disaster.

You *contribute to* that collection when you give something to it.

In your example, only the first version works. Here, it's about selling rather than giving. Less than 10% of the seafood bought from overseas by the US came from Indonesia.

The second would mean that, out of 10% of the total, *some* came from Indonesia (which doesn't make sense).